Controlling number of request per second using well defined mechanism?
I have below implementation this service is responsible for sending data to third party service and i want to control how many data we can send per second lets suppose i have 10000 records in each second i want to send 125 records i have tried circuit breaker as well but this seems not give us control to send request per second ?
@Slf4j
public class StandardApiCallServiceImpl implements ApiCallService {
    
    private static final int HAPI_HTTP_CODE_NOT_MODIFIED = 1304;
    private final ServiceLocator serviceLocator;
    private final EntityCacheService entityCacheService;

    public StandardApiCallServiceImpl(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, EntityCacheService entityCacheService) {
        this.serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
        this.entityCacheService = entityCacheService;
    }

    @Override
    public void makeApiCall(List<EntityCache> entityCaches) {
        for (EntityCache entity : entityCaches) {
           manageEntityCache(entity);
        }
    }

    protected void manageEntityCache(final EntityCache entityCache) {
        try {
            final Response vioohResponse = send(entityCache);
            updateExecutionInformation(
                    entityCache,
                    calculateStatus(entityCache, response),
                    response
            );
        } catch (final HapiCacheEntityException hapiCacheEntityException) {
            updateExecutionInformation(entityCache, StatusType.CACHED, VioohResponse.builder()
                    .isSuccessful(true)
                    .httpCode(HAPI_HTTP_CODE_NOT_MODIFIED)
                    .build()
            );
            log.info("entity was cached and was not resent by hapi: {}", entityCache);
        } catch (final Exception exception) {
            log.error("error occurred when trying to send this entity cache: {}, error: {}", entityCache, exception.getMessage());
        }

    }

    protected Response send(final EntityCache entityCache) {
        final EntityType entityType = EntityType.valueOf(entityCache.getEntityType().getCode());

        return serviceLocator.find(entityType.getFamilyType())
                .send(entityType, entityCache);
    }


Give me best possible approach to send control number of request and handle failover ?

Now if only such a thing like a RateLimiter would exist.

I tried rate limiter as well but my problem is this makeApiCall will call in multithreaded env so it can't control correctly ?

Why wouldn't it that is the whole point of the ratelimiter to limit concurrent requests (either incoming or outgoing dependending on the use). You need to configure and define it once then reuse, don't redefine it each time you need one as that would be pointless.
